# Slow query ordering by a column in a joined table

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, sql-order-by, collation

Introducing an ORDER BY clause in a query increases the total time due the extra work that the db have to do in order to sort the result set:

- copy the resulting tuples in some temporary memory
- sorting them (hopefully in memory, otherwise using the disk)
- stream the result to the client

What I miss is why just adding a column from a joined table produces a so different performance.

#### Query1

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT p.*
FROM product_product p
JOIN django_site d ON (p.site_id = d.id)
WHERE (p.active = true  AND p.site_id = 1 )
ORDER BY d.domain, p.ordering, p.name
```

#### Query plan

```
Sort  (cost=3909.83..3952.21 rows=16954 width=1086) (actual time=1120.618..1143.922 rows=16946 loops=1)
   Sort Key: django_site.domain, product_product.ordering, product_product.name
   Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 25517kB
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..2718.86 rows=16954 width=1086) (actual time=0.053..87.396 rows=16946 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on django_site  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.010..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)
               Filter: (id = 1)
         ->  Seq Scan on product_product  (cost=0.00..2548.31 rows=16954 width=1066) (actual time=0.036..44.138 rows=16946 loops=1)
               Filter: (product_product.active AND (product_product.site_id = 1))
 Total runtime: 1182.515 ms
```

#### Query 2

Same as the above but not sorting by `django_site.domain`

#### Query plan

```
 Sort  (cost=3909.83..3952.21 rows=16954 width=1066) (actual time=257.094..278.905 rows=16946 loops=1)
   Sort Key: product_product.ordering, product_product.name
   Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 25161kB
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..2718.86 rows=16954 width=1066) (actual time=0.075..86.120 rows=16946 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on django_site  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.015..0.017 rows=1 loops=1)
               Filter: (id = 1)
         ->  Seq Scan on product_product  (cost=0.00..2548.31 rows=16954 width=1066) (actual time=0.052..44.024 rows=16946 loops=1)
               Filter: (product_product.active AND (product_product.site_id = 1))
 Total runtime: 305.392 ms
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261900/postgres-order-by-foreign-key-performance) could be related.

### Edit: More details added

```
           Table "public.product_product"
 Column       |          Type          |  
 -------------+------------------------+---------
 id                | integer                | not null default nextval('product_product_id_seq'::regclass)
 site_id           | integer                | not null
 name              | character varying(255) | not null
 slug              | character varying(255) | not null
 sku               | character varying(255) | 
 ordering          | integer                | not null
 [snip some columns ]

 Indexes:
    "product_product_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "product_product_site_id_key" UNIQUE, btree (site_id, sku)
    "product_product_site_id_key1" UNIQUE, btree (site_id, slug)
    "product_product_site_id" btree (site_id)
    "product_product_slug" btree (slug)
    "product_product_slug_like" btree (slug varchar_pattern_ops)


                  Table "public.django_site"
 Column |          Type          | 
--------+------------------------+----------
 id     | integer                | not null default nextval('django_site_id_seq'::regclass)
 domain | character varying(100) | not null
 name   | character varying(50)  | not null
Indexes:
    "django_site_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

The Postgres version is **8.4**

## some table stats:

```
# select count(*) from django_site;
 count 
-------
     1

# select count(*) from product_product;
 count 
-------
 17540

# select active, count(*) from product_product group by active;
 active | count 
--------+-------
 f      |   591
 t      | 16949

# select site_id, count(*) from product_product group by site_id;
 site_id | count 
---------+-------
       1 | 17540
```

Comment: Site_id should be (part of) a key field in both tables. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE is identical up to the sort operation, so sorting makes the difference.

In both queries you return all rows of `product_product`, but in the first case you sort by a column of `django_site`, so `django_site.domain` has to be retrieved in addition, that costs extra. But would not explain the big difference.

There is a good chance that the **physical order** of the rows in `product_product` is already according to the column `ordering`, which makes the sort in case 2 very cheap and the sort in case 1 expensive.

---

After "more details added":
It is also **considerably more expensive** so sort by `character varying(100)` than to sort by an `integer` column. In addition to integer being much smaller, there is also the collation support that slows you down. To verify, try ordering with `COLLATE "C"`. Read more about [collation support in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/collation.html).
If you **were** running PostgreSQL 9.1. I see now, that you have PostgreSQL 8.4.

Obviously, all rows in the query output have the same value for `django_site.domain` as you filter on `p.site_id = 1`. If the query planner was smarter, it might skip the first column for ordering to begin with.

You run PostgreSQL 8.4. The query planner of 9.1 has become considerably more intelligent. Upgrading might change the situation, but I can't say for certain.

---

To verify my theory about physical ordering, you could try and make a copy of your big table with the rows inserted in random order and then run the queries again. Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE p AS
SELECT *
FROM   public.product_product
ORDER  BY random();
```

And then:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT p.*
FROM   p
JOIN   django_site d ON (p.site_id = d.id)
WHERE  p.active
AND    p.site_id = 1
ORDER  BY d.domain, p.ordering, p.name;
```

Any difference? --> Obviously that doesn't explain it ...

---

OK, to test whether the `varchar(100)` makes the difference, I recreated your scenario. See the [**separate answer with a detailed test case and benchmark**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9908333/939860). This answer is overloaded already.

To sum it up:
Turns out, my other explanation fits. The main reason for the slowdown is obviously sorting by a `varchar(100)` column according to a [locale (`LC_COLLATE`)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/locale.html).

I added some explanation and links to the [test case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9908333/939860). The results should speak for themselves.

Comment: The two outputs are not equal, the estimated costs are, but not the actual time. Obviously the two query plan are identical.

Comment: @dvd: Well, the planned operations are the same. Just in the one case, the sort turns out to be much more expensive - for reasons that we are speculating about right now.

Comment: Brandstetter: here I am, I have created the table using order by random() (I've pasted your code) and the results are the same: >1sec with d.domain in the order clause, <400msec without it

Comment: Brandsetter: Same behavior with Postgres 9.1

Comment: @dvd: See te results of my test. Gotta run now, numbers should speak for themselves.

Comment: @Brandstetter: you have nailed it changing the ORDER clause in ORDER BY "django_site"."domain" COLLATE "C" ASC, "product_product"."ordering" ASC, "product_product"."name" ASC do the trick

Answer (score 10):

### Test Case

PostgreSQL 9.1. Test database with limited resources, but way enough for this small case. The locale for collation will be relevant:

```
SHOW LC_COLLATE;

 de_AT.UTF-8
```

Step 1) Reconstruct raw test environment

```
-- DROP TABLE x;
CREATE SCHEMA x;  -- test schema

-- DROP TABLE x.django_site;
CREATE TABLE x.django_site (
id serial primary key
,domain character varying(100) not null
,int_col int not null
);
INSERT INTO x.django_site values (1,'www.testsite.com/foodir/', 3);

-- DROP TABLE x.product;
CREATE TABLE x.product (
 id serial primary key
,site_id integer not null
,name character varying(255) not null
,slug character varying(255) not null
,sku character varying(255) 
,ordering integer not null
,active boolean not null
);

INSERT INTO x.product (site_id, name, slug, sku, ordering, active)
SELECT 1
    ,repeat(chr((random() * 255)::int + 32), (random()*255)::int)
    ,repeat(chr((random() * 255)::int + 32), (random()*255)::int)
    ,repeat(chr((random() * 255)::int + 32), (random()*255)::int)
    ,i -- ordering in sequence
    ,NOT (random()* 0.5174346569119122)::int::bool
FROM generate_series(1, 17540) AS x(i);
-- SELECT ((591::float8 / 17540)* 0.5) / (1 - (591::float8 / 17540))
-- = 0.5174346569119122

CREATE INDEX product_site_id on x.product(site_id);
```

Step 2) ANALYZE

```
    ANALYZE x.product;
    ANALYZE x.django_site;
```

Step 3) Reorder BY random()

```
-- DROP TABLE x.p;
CREATE TABLE x.p AS
SELECT *
FROM   x.product
ORDER  BY random();

ANALYZE x.p;
```

---

#### Results

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
    SELECT p.*
    FROM   x.p
    JOIN   x.django_site d ON (p.site_id = d.id)
    WHERE  p.active
    AND    p.site_id = 1
--    ORDER  BY d.domain, p.ordering, p.name
--    ORDER  BY p.ordering, p.name
--    ORDER  BY d.id, p.ordering, p.name
--    ORDER  BY d.int_col, p.ordering, p.name
--    ORDER  BY p.name COLLATE "C"
--    ORDER  BY d.domain COLLATE "C", p.ordering, p.name -- dvd's final solution
```

1) Pre ANALYZE (-> bitmap index scan)
2) Post ANALYZE (-> seq scan)
3) Re-order by random(), ANALYZE

```
ORDER  BY d.domain, p.ordering, p.name
```

1)  Total runtime: 1253.543 ms
2)  Total runtime: 1250.351 ms
3)  Total runtime: 1283.111 ms

```
ORDER  BY p.ordering, p.name
```

1)  Total runtime: 177.266 ms
2)  Total runtime: 174.556 ms
3)  Total runtime: 177.797 ms

```
ORDER  BY d.id, p.ordering, p.name
```

1)  Total runtime: 176.628 ms
2)  Total runtime: 176.811 ms
3)  Total runtime: 178.150 ms
*The planner obviously factors in that `d.id` is functionally dependent.*

```
ORDER  BY d.int_col, p.ordering, p.name -- integer column in other table
```

1)  Total runtime: 242.218 ms   -- !!
2)  Total runtime: 245.234 ms
3)  Total runtime: **254.581 ms**
*The planner obviously misses that `d.int_col` (NOT NULL) is just as functionally dependent. But sorting by an integer column is cheap.*

```
ORDER  BY p.name -- varchar(255) in same table
```

1)  Total runtime: 2259.171 ms  -- !!
2)  Total runtime: 2257.650 ms
3)  Total runtime: **2258.282 ms**
*Sorting by a (long) `varchar` or `text` column is expensive ...*

```
ORDER  BY p.name COLLATE "C"
```

1)  Total runtime: 327.516 ms   -- !!
2)  Total runtime: 325.103 ms
3)  Total runtime: **327.206 ms**
*... but not as expensive if done without locale.*

With the locale out of the way, sorting by a `varchar` column is not quite but almost as fast. Locale `"C"` is effectively "no locale, just order by byte value". I [quote the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/locale.html#AEN31366):

> If you want the system to behave as if it had no locale support, use
>   the special locale name C, or equivalently POSIX.

---

Putting it all together, @dvd chose:

```
ORDER  BY d.domain COLLATE "C", p.ordering, p.name
```

...
3) Total runtime: **275.854 ms**
*That should do.*

Comment: You beat me again. I just finished typing the table-creation and population. In fact the optimiser should see that d.domain is functionally dependant on p.site_id = d.id. I even added an FK constraint, but that did not help. Also: the rowsize in the OP is very large, about 1K.

Comment: Yeah, the optimizer has a blind spot there. As `p.site_id` has a `=` condition on it and the other involved columns `d.id, d.domain` are NOT NULL, ordering by `d.domain` logically has no effect. There is potential for a smarter planner. Do you think the row size has an additional effect?

Comment: It looks like the 25M work mem accomodates all the 17K * 1K records. And the final ORDER BY has to walk the full length if the *identical* .domain strings. The optimiser *could* have known this (Functional dependance site_id -> domain leading to equivalence classes for the domain<->domain compare. Character encoding / collation seems to make things even worse). I'll look into the source, when I find time. Maybe inform Tom Lane?

Comment: A very interesting case, indeed. One more condition: `d.id` is unique. (If it wasn't there could be multiple values for `d.domain`.) I will be away for a few days. Happy hacking!

Comment: It is not only unique, it is anchored to a constant. But there appear to be a lot of cases lately, where the final ordering (+ LIMIT ...) is throwing crawbars into the nice machinery. Happy hiking!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see, you need some indexes

1. create index product_product_idx01 on product_product(active, site_id);
   This probably will speed up your query.
2. why do you order by domain, it's meanless your query

Comment: The index does not help in this case, the query is spending his time sorting not filtering and the first column of the order by is not covered by the index. The domain column is added automatically by django (site app), I will open a ticket for this but before patching the code I want to know If I can tune the db.

Comment: The two seqscans are suspect. If the site_id would have been (the 1st part of) the key/FK, this would not have happened. Please add the table definitions, including indexes/key constraints. BTW how unique is stie_id anyway?

Comment: You should add this index:) if i'm mistaken you can drop it any time. Record quantity is very small for query to be so expensive

Comment: @Pavieg Sorry for not being clear, I've tested your suggestion and then dropped the index because it didn't gave any advantage