# Should I save ASCII-only varchar in UTF-8 or ASCII?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, locale

I have a `varchar` column that contains only ASCII symbols. I don't need to sort by this field, but I need to search it by full equality.

Default locale is `en.UTF8`. Will I gain anything if I create this column with `collate "C"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, it makes a difference.

Even if you do not sort deliberately, there are various operations requiring sort steps internally (some aggregate functions, `DISTINCT`, nested loop joins etc.).

Also, any **index** on the field has to sort values internally - and observe collation rules unless `COLLATE "C"` applies (no collation rules).

For searches by *full equality* you'll want an index - which works either way (for equality), but it's faster overall without collation rules. Depending on the details of your use case, the effect may be negligible or substantial. The impact grows with the length of your strings. I ran a benchmark on a related case some time ago:

- [Slow query ordering by a column in a joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888096/slow-query-ordering-by-a-column-in-a-joined-table/9891010#9891010)

Also, there are more pattern matching options with locale "C". The alternative would be to create an index with the special `varchar_pattern_ops` operator class.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)
- [Operator “~<~” uses varchar_pattern_ops index while normal ORDER BY clause doesn't?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/94868/3684)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

**Postgres 9.5** introduced performance improvements with a technique called **"abbreviated keys"**, which ran into problems with some locales. So it was deactivated, except for the `C` locale. [Quoting The release notes of Postgres 9.5.2:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/release-9-5-2.html)

> - Disable abbreviated keys for string sorting in non-`C` locales (Robert Haas)
>
> PostgreSQL 9.5 introduced logic for speeding up comparisons of string
> data types by using the standard C library function `strxfrm()` as a
> substitute for `strcoll()`. It now emerges that most versions of glibc
> (Linux's implementation of the C library) have buggy implementations
> of `strxfrm()` that, in some locales, can produce string comparison
> results that do not match `strcoll()`. Until this problem can be better
> characterized, disable the optimization in all non-C locales. (`C`
> locale is safe since it uses neither `strcoll()` nor `strxfrm()`.)
>
> Unfortunately, this problem affects not only sorting but also entry
> ordering in B-tree indexes, which means that B-tree indexes on `text`,
> `varchar`, or `char` columns may now be corrupt if they sort according to
> an affected locale and were built or modified under PostgreSQL 9.5.0
> or 9.5.1. Users should `REINDEX` indexes that might be affected.
>
> It is not possible at this time to give an exhaustive list of
> known-affected locales. `C` locale is known safe, and there is no
> evidence of trouble in English-based locales such as `en_US`, but some
> other popular locales such as `de_DE` are affected in most glibc
> versions.

The problem also illustrates where collation rules come in, generally.